# Heroku Postgres Database is not working in my Django project

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, heroku

I created a Django project and tried to deploy it on Heroku and was working at first. But after adding another model in my `models.py` this new model does not show up on the admin-side on the heroku deploy but it works locally (when I run `python manage.py runserver`)

I am using Heroku Postgres for the database on Heroku. I also already ran `heroku run python manage.py makemigrations` and `heroku run python manage.py migrate` , and I reseted the database completely, but still only two of the three models are showing up on the admin-side.

Comment: Have you registered your new model with admin?

Comment: yes, as I said it works locally but it does not work on heroku.

Comment: Then it sounds like you've not deployed something to heroku. Possibly the registration of the model with admin. Verify that (a) the new model is in the DB on Heroku using the django shell there and (b) that the code registering this model in `admin.py` has deployed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer to my problem was, In the `settings.py` at the `INSTALLED_APPS`:
I added my app at the top, like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  "my_app.apps.my_appConfig",
  "django.contrib.admin",
  "django.contrib.auth",
  "django.contrib.contenttypes",
  "django.contrib.sessions",
  "django.contrib.messages",
  "django.contrib.staticfiles",
]
```

and not at the bottom:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  "django.contrib.admin",
  "django.contrib.auth",
  "django.contrib.contenttypes",
  "django.contrib.sessions",
  "django.contrib.messages",
  "django.contrib.staticfiles",
  "my_app.apps.my_appConfig",
]
```

For some reason it only works when added at the bottom.